# iReport Text Field Spacing Issues

Tags: jasper-reports

My report is showing some very odd spacing issues. It had values that were being repeated, muliple times, but i fixed that by unselecting the `Print Repeated Values` check box. This fixed the repeated values from displaying. Afterwards I noticed that there were some spaces that were showing up after unselecting that so I then selected the `Remove Line When Blank` check box. That should have fixed the spacing but for some odd reason I am still seeing some very odd spacing issues in the Preview of my report. Here are some pictures showing what I have. Does anyone have any idea why it would still be doing this; even after I have done the correct options for spacing/repeating values?

**Spacing Issue:**

[image: Spacing Issue]

**Shows the Checked Property boxes for all 'Text Fields'**

[image: Shows the Checked Property boxes for all 'Text Fields']

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports      http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="BOM Build Time" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="775a7e35-9af8-4206-a155-b05a478c35b0">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="bomNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="From" class="java.util.Date"/>
<parameter name="To" class="java.util.Date"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT
 datediff(day,MO."DATECREATED",MO."DATECOMPLETED") AS dayToBuild,
 COMPANY."NAME" AS COMPANY_NAME,
 BOM."NUM" AS BOM_NUM,
 MO."DATECREATED" AS MO_DATECREATED,
 MO."NUM" AS MO_NUM,
 MO."DATECOMPLETED" AS MO_DATECOMPLETED,
 MOITEM."BOMID" AS MOITEM_BOMID,
 MOITEM."MOID" AS MOITEM_MOID,
 MOITEM."QTYTOFULFILL" AS MOITEM_QTYTOFULFILL,
 BOMITEMTYPE."ID" AS BOMITEMTYPE_ID
 FROM
 "BOM" BOM INNER JOIN "MOITEM" MOITEM ON BOM."ID" = MOITEM."BOMID"
 INNER JOIN "MO" MO ON MOITEM."MOID" = MO."ID"
 INNER JOIN "BOMITEMTYPE" BOMITEMTYPE ON MOITEM."TYPEID" = BOMITEMTYPE."ID",
 "COMPANY" COMPANY
 WHERE
BOM."NUM"=$P{bomNumber}
AND MO."DATECOMPLETED" BETWEEN $P{To} AND $P{From}
 ORDER BY
 3 ASC]]>
</queryString>
<field name="DAYTOBUILD" class="java.lang.Long"/>
<field name="COMPANY_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="BOM_NUM" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="MO_DATECREATED" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
<field name="MO_NUM" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="MO_DATECOMPLETED" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
<field name="MOITEM_BOMID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="MOITEM_MOID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<field name="MOITEM_QTYTOFULFILL" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="BOMITEMTYPE_ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
<variable name="timeToBuild" class="java.lang.String">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{MO_DATECOMPLETED}.getTime()-          $F{MO_DATECREATED}.getTime()) / (24* 60 * 60 * 1000)  + " days " +
 (($F{MO_DATECOMPLETED}.getTime()-$F{MO_DATECREATED}.getTime()) / (60 * 60 * 1000)) % 24 + " hour(s), " +
 (($F{MO_DATECOMPLETED}.getTime()-$F{MO_DATECREATED}.getTime()) / (60 * 1000)) % 60 + " minute(s)"]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="avgTimeToBuild" class="java.lang.String"      incrementType="Report" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{timeToBuild}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<title>
    <band height="33" splitType="Stretch"/>
</title>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="32" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="100" height="20"      uuid="b59f6065-7fc9-482d-9e08-e381ac697304"/>
            <text><![CDATA[BOM_NUM]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="108" y="0" width="100" height="20"      uuid="4ec40990-bdfe-415d-a7ae-b50e315d00ef"/>
            <text><![CDATA[MO_DATECREATED]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="218" y="0" width="100" height="20"      uuid="032d2ae9-99fe-4c6f-8cf4-24b9c5367a44"/>
            <text><![CDATA[MO_DATECOMPLETED]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="329" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="55b731d5-b826-4ee1-b7d2-4a83cabd4ef8"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Time To Build]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="24" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0"      width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="3b256693-f18d-4ef9-89ec-7890481d1855"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{BOM_NUM}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="108" y="0" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="7c01356e-4c95-4e15-9691-632e0b84946e"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MO_DATECREATED}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="218" y="0" width="100" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="516bc38e-99f3-486f-ae74-c8cfe6a5b5b1"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MO_DATECOMPLETED}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="329" y="0" width="150" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="aa538d4a-48ec-4b72-84ed-e9e889dcaee5"/>
            <textElement>
                <paragraph tabStopWidth="40"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{timeToBuild}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="479" y="0" width="76" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="cf252514-6297-405d-a12e-6424332e6d10"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MOITEM_QTYTOFULFILL}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<summary>
    <band height="22">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="125" height="20" uuid="5ac0e1eb-dc7b-4866-88aa-3c1a9c3ef4a9"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Average Time To Build:]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="125" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="860dd902-9791-443e-9a9d-3dedab365b23"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{avgTimeToBuild}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</summary>
```

Comment: Can you please included the jrxml in the question (it's more useful than then screenshot of ireport, since it defines exactly your report), edit the question

Comment: @PetterFriberg i added your requested JRXML file- please help if you can. Thanks!

Comment: The only thing if find is incorrect variables definition of $V{avgTimeToBuild}, maybe you have trouble compiling the report (hence you are displaying an old .jasper.

Comment: You still have issues with this or did you find the problem...

Comment: I figured out the solution and I will post it in a few